# Taxonomy term node count with depth

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I want to achieve the following term listing:

- clothing (17)

  - dresses (2)
  - skirts (3)
  - tops (12)
- accessories (5)

  - bags (1)
  - jewelery (4)
  - necklaces (2)
  - rings (2)

Is this possible with views? I know you can use the "Taxonomy Term: Content with term" relationship, but this only counts the nodes attached to the parent terms and not those attached to the child terms...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with only views. Here is a good thread to get you started. http://drupal.org/node/301485#comment-1065230

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step instructions with screen shots to create a view,

http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-use-views-aggregator-to-create-taxonomy-term-count-block